# Can we use MongoDB for Temporary storage?

Tags: node.js, database, mean-stack

I want to create a database which stores the user data for a temporary period of time (i.e) Until the user logout.

Once the user logged out, I want all the details they are provided to get deleted.

My question is, can we use mongoDB for temporary storage. Until the user logout!

Or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you can. Also, you can use any other database for this.

Comment: It sounds like you want a RAM-only database, and in this case I think you would be better off using plain old JSON objects (or an array or something that gets overwritten with zeroes) because when you say "delete" in a normal database it really just says "okay this sector we can write over again" but the data is still there if someone were to do forensics on it.  You want to overwrite the old sectors and the best way would be variables (that live in RAM) .. if you want to be certain the data is no longer accessible.  Depends on your security/privacy concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any database to do that. Just delete the data when the user logs out.

Redis may be a good fit for that because it stores the data in RAM, see:

- http://redis.io/

But really any database can do it. You will just have to remove the data on logout.

Since you tagged your question with "mean-stack" then I assume that you're using Express. There are some modules that can help you with what you're trying to do. See the [Compatible Session Stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) in the [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) documentation.

Some of the more relevant modules from that list:

- [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) (for Mongo, as you asked)
- [connect-mongodb-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session) (another one for Mongo)
- [connect-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis) (for Redis, which is well suited for that use case)
- [connect-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-sqlite3) (for SQLite, an embedded RDBMS that you don't have to install)
- [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store) (for storing session data in files)
- or you can use the default in-memory session storage for testing (not suitable for production)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is yes, you can use mongoDB for temporary storage. You can even set a TTL for the document so it will expire after an amount of time.

Here is the link for the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Another solution would be to store that kind of information in a database that persists only in memory like [Redis](http://redis.io/). That way you could gain some performance even.

Comment: When the user is idle, how we can perform logout scenario? Like how can we set TTL